# Is there a theory which is not the theory of finitely many of its models?

Tags: model-theory

Let $L$ be a signature, in the sense of model theory. Does there exist an $L$-theory $T$ such that for no finite set of models $\{M_1,...,M_n\}$ of $T$ is it the case that $Th(\{M_1,...,M_n\})=T$? In other words, is there a signature $L$ and a theory $T$ such that $T$ is not the theory of finitely many of its models?

Comment: Sure. Any theory with infinitely many distinct completions will have this property. In particular, any theory to which Godel's incompleteness theorem applies will do (PA, ZFC, ...). Did you want to add some additional hypotheses?

Comment: @NoahSchweber That should be an answer.

Comment: @Noah: unfortunately I'm not seeing how either of those claims follows (either that a theory with infinitely many distinct completions has the desired property, or that a theory to which the incompleteness theorem applies has the desired property). Can you write a more detailed answer?

Comment: If $Th(\{M_1,...,M_n\})=T$ then clearly eveyt finite model of $T$ must be isomorphic to one of your $M_i$. So any theory with infinitely many nonisomorphic finite models will be the example you want.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Recall that for a class $\mathbb{K}$ of structures, $Th(\mathbb{K})$ is the **common theory** of the elements of $\mathbb{K}$, that is, $Th(\mathbb{K})=\bigcap_{\mathcal{M}\in\mathbb{K}}Th(\mathcal{M})$.*

---

I claim that the theories of the form $Th(\mathbb{K})$ for some finite set of structures $\mathbb{K}$ are exactly those which have finitely many completions - that is, whose model classes are finite *up to elementarily equivalence*.

- First, suppose $T$ has only finitely many completions. Let $M_1,...,M_n$ be models of those completions. Then we clearly have $Th(\{M_1,...,M_n\})\supseteq T$. Conversely, if $\varphi\in Th(\{M_1,...,M_n\})$, then every completion of $T$ entails $\varphi$ which means that $T\models\varphi$ (think about $T\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$).
- In the other direction, suppose that $T=Th(\{M_1,...,M_n\})$. Then I claim that $T$ is (up to model class) just the set $$X:=\{\mu_1\vee...\vee\mu_n: M_1\models \mu_1,...,M_n\models\mu_n\}.$$ Clearly we have $Mod(T)\supseteq Mod(X)$; conversely, if $N\not\models T$ then there must be sentences $\nu_i\in Th(M_i)$ ($1\le i\le n$) such that $N\models\neg\nu_i$, but then $N\not\models X$.

As an example, suppose $T$ is computably axiomatizable but essentially undecidable (= has no computable completion). Then no completion of $T$ is finitely axiomatizable over $T$; consequently, $T$ has continuum-many completions *(combinatorially: every dead-end-free binary tree with no isolated paths has continuum-many paths)*, and so cannot be the common theory of a finite set of structures.

Comment: I find it illuminating to think about this in terms of Stone duality on the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra.  Theories correspond to closed subsets of the space of complete theories, and so the nontrivial direction of your argument is just the fact that a finite set of complete theories is closed.  (And your example at the end is a closed set with no isolated points, which must then be uncountable.)